# Build my own website and host it

Tags: web-development

This question is probably a repetition but considering my rudimentary understanding I am ready to bear the wrath of experts who don't want to answer it.

I just bought a domain name and registered it using a provider in India with .com ending. I want to build my own website here in USA, own it and host it with a provider in India.

Can you please suggest free website builder which I can use to host in India? I don't want to use online website builders like [Weebly](https://www.weebly.com) as I can't just walk away with my files if I want to since I will be using their template.

Comment: So your provider already includes the webserver; you just need to create files and then upload them. Is that right? If so, we would need to know which technologies are supported. Does it just serve HTML pages or is PHP allowed?

Comment: Another question: what are you willing to pay and on which OS (Windows?) would you want to use the website builder?

Comment: http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-html-editor.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is nothing more free than using [Notepad](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_editors.asp)! Crack open Notepad (I'd actually suggest [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.3.1.html)) and off you go. Whilst not free, could run up a WordPress sight at $17.00 per year:

[image: Mapped Domain]

[HTML Basics](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp), [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) and [Media Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) can help you get started if you do not know hot to use HTML or CSS (I have not added Javascript etc.) at all.

Go ahead, [download a template file](http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates) and start digging for gold. Be careful though and try to host your files online rather than `a href="C:\filers\picture`otherwise you may run into issues online.

**Pro Tip:** See something cool on a website you want to recreate? Use the 'View Souce' in a browser to view the code, or save the website as HTML and inspect - just don't copy their entire website without permission, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter where you are hosting the website, development is usually done locally on your computer and if all fits, then you copy the while project to your hoster per FTP.

So first you need to install a webserver on your machine, two well known, free and easy to setup products are [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html) and [Wamp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/). With one of those webservers on your machine you can play around with your site and even debug the code to find problems.

There are many web-site generators available, unfortunately I'm not familiar with them and cannot give advise. If you are serious about web development though, you could have a look at [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/).